# How can I plot piece-wise function with legend using tikz?

Tags: pgfplots, legend

I have a piece-wise function (actually, some points connected with a line in a region) and I want to add a legend. My problem is that if I add several `\addplot` segments, the `\addlegendentry` displays wrong legend (it is shifted). (I have more than one function.)

Comment: Can you provide a MWE?

Comment: You can maybe add `forget plot` to the `\addplot` that you don't want to add a legend entry to. But without a MWE, it is difficult to provide a good solution.

Comment: Many thanks, "forget plot" was I was looking for

Comment: I’m voting to close this question because according to the OPs comment, the problem seems to be solved.